# How do I append more data to an AngularJS model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

So far I'm having no issue setting up an AngularJS model in my Rails application and giving it data to access on the front-end.  I even set it up to be populated with data from an AJAX request using `$http`.  However, I need this this model to contain the data of multiple `$http` calls.  Here's the code I've got thus far:

```
function DropboxCtrl($scope, $http) {
    var $infiniteLoader = $(".infiniteLoader");
    var theUIDS = $infiniteLoader.attr('data-dropbox-uids').split(',');

    if($infiniteLoader.attr('data-dropbox-uids') != "") {
        var theData = {};

        $.each(theUIDS, function(key) {
            $http({ url: '/dropbox/files/get', method: 'GET', params: { uid: theUIDS[key] }}).success(function(data) {
                theData = data;
            });
        });

        $scope.dropboxes = theData;
    }
}
```

I have a method called `DropboxCtrl` which will start by getting all the UID's that I need to call a GET request on.  I loop through each of them and then append `data` to `theData` which is a Javascript object.  After the each I make my dropboxes model equal to the value of `theData`.  Current I've got the method returning absolutely nothing and no Javascript errors.  I am positive that my url works completely and actually did get the code working with just one AJAX request like such:

```
$.each(theUIDS, function(key) {
    $http({ url: '/dropbox/files/get', method: 'GET', params: { uid: theUIDS[key] }}).success(function(data) {
        $scope.dropboxes = data;
    });
});
```

However... that code block only returns the last AJAX call because the other ones are overwritten.  Maybe what I'm missing is just incorrect Javascript, however, maybe what I'm missing is just a lack of understanding the "Angular way" of things.  I'm skilled in Javascript and jQuery, but very new to Angular.  Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJs is a high level Javascript framework. The code ultimately is javascript. Within your $each, you can push results to an array or to an initialized collection like

```
$scope.dropboxes = [{uid:1234}, {uid:2345}] and so on.
```

within the $each, locate the record for uid and attach the results.
I usually use underscorejs library for operations on collections, arrays etc.
so something like

```
_.findWhere($scope.dropboxes, {uid: data.uid }).data = data;
```

assuming the data that is returned has uid in it. If not then there should be another way to map the results to the request. Note that there is no guarantee of the order of responses, so you cannot use array indexes to map results.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, I'm a bit new to Angular (and have never used UnderscoreJS), could you give me a bit of context?  I don't quite understand your answer.

Comment: All I am trying to say is you need to map your responses to the appropriate request. Because you are making more than 1 async call and the order of response is not guaranteed, you will have to find a way to push the response back into the appropriate request item in the collection.

Underscore is simply a javascript library that provides useful functions to find, filter, etc on collections and arrays. You really do not have to use it, it's just productive.

Comment: The important thing to remember is to 

1. Initialize a collection of objects that will have your uid as a property before you make any call.
2. Within the $each loop above, when you get the response back, locate the item in that collection based on uid and then attach the response back to that item in the "data" property.
3. When you get all the responses back, you will have a collection of objects each with uid and data as 2 properties.

Comment: Makes sense to me.  I'll go ahead and mark your answer as correct, but I should let you know I've decided to go another route.  Technically speaking though, your answer would be close enough to correct for me to accept.  Thanks!